# ¿Porque si entra al bucle if o no depende de una linea que solo imprime un valor?

Tags: php

Tengo este código que se comporta de manera extraña cuando comento o descomento una linea:

```
<?php
$_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "y su contraseña");
$_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$_pdo->exec("USE data_base");
$seleccion = $_pdo->prepare("SELECT nombre, apellido FROM data_base");
$seleccion->execute();
$resultado = $seleccion->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//echo count($seleccion->fetchAll()); Si lo comento el if se ejecuta si no lo comento el else se ejecuta
if(count($seleccion->fetchAll())>0){
  echo "Se ejecuta";
}else{
  echo "El if fallo";
}
?>
```

Lo que quiero entender porque si lo comento se ejecuta el if y sino se ejecuta el else, ya que lo único que hace esa linea es imprimir la longitud del array, ¿Por qué ocurre eso?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Si necesitan que les muestre la tabla me lo dicen, aunque no creo que sea por eso, pero no se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion `fetchAll()` devuelve un arreglo con todas los registros y vacia el buffer.  En otras palabras, despues de llamar esta funcion, la variable `$seleccion` queda vacia.  Si quieres saber la cantidad de registros, te sugiero esta otra query:

```
SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM data_base;
```